# ${\rm Fun}^R(C_1^\text{op},C_2)$ is a presentable category

Tags: category-theory

I am stuck in proving Lemma 5.25 in Moritz Groth's [notes](http://www.math.ru.nl/~mgroth/preprints/groth_scinfinity.pdf): I am asked to prove that for any two presentable categories $C_1,C_2$ the category of limit preserving functors ${\rm Fun}^R(C_1^\text{op},C_2)$ is again presentable.

Groth solves the particular case $C_1=[E_1^{op},{\bf Sets}]$, appealing thm 2.39 in Adamek-Rosicky's book; then he says "With some more effort the general case can also be established."

The proof given by Groth in that particular case seems to rely on the equivalence $Adj(\widehat{E_1},C_2^{op})\cong Fun(E_1,C_2^{op})$ established via "nerve-realization", so I'm not able to generalize it.

What is the idea behind the general case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A limit-preserving functor $\mathcal{C}_1^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{C}_2$ is a colimit-preserving functor $\mathcal{C}_1 \to \mathcal{C}_2^\mathrm{op}$.
2. If $\mathcal{C}_1$ is a locally $\kappa$-presentable category and $\mathcal{A}_1$ is the full subcategory of $\kappa$-compact objects in $\mathcal{C}_1$, then the category of $\kappa$-accessible functors $\mathcal{C}_1 \to \mathcal{C}_2^\mathrm{op}$ is equivalent to the functor category $[\mathcal{A}_1, \mathcal{C}_2^\mathrm{op}]$.
3. The full subcategory of colimit-preserving functors $\mathcal{C}_1 \to \mathcal{C}_2^\mathrm{op}$ can be identified with the full subcategory of $\kappa$-small colimit-preserving functors $[\mathcal{A}_1, \mathcal{C}_2^\mathrm{op}]$: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/494245/5191). Thus the full subcategory of limit-preserving functors $\mathcal{C}_1^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{C}_2$ can be identified with the full subcategory of $\kappa$-small limit-preserving functors $\mathcal{A}_1^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{C}_2$.
4. $\mathcal{A}_1$ has all $\kappa$-small colimits, because $\mathcal{C}_1$ is cocomplete. Thus the category of $\kappa$-small limit-preserving functors $\mathcal{A}_1^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{C}_2$ is the category of models for a limit sketch in the locally presentable category $\mathcal{C}_2$, which is again locally presentable by Theorem 2.60 in [Adámek and Rosický]. (It is clear that any such category is complete, and it is known that a complete accessible category is locally presentable.)

Comment: It seems far more than "some" more effort... Anyway, thank you :) a difficult proof is better than no proof at all.

Comment: The idea is really the same in the end: a locally $\kappa$-presentable category is equivalent to the category of $\kappa$-small limit preserving functors from a small $\kappa$-complete category to $\mathbf{Set}$. So you just have to keep track of more conditions than the presheaf case.